# WAV file written with AudioSegment.export() sounds half the speed as when rewriting the file with Soundfile.write

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, audio-processing, pydub, soundfile

I am currently processing some audio data. I have an audio file that I have created from splitting a larger file on silence using pydub.

However, if I take this audio file after exporting it with pydub, and then convert the AudioSegment's array to numpy array, and re-write it using soundfile, I get an audio file written that is about half the speed as it was originally. What could be going wrong?

```
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np

from pydub import AudioSegment, effects
from pathlib import Path

# This code takes a large .mp3 file ("original_audio_mp3") with sample rate of 44100 khz
sound = AudioSegment.from_file(original_audio_mp3)
if sound.frame_rate != desired_sample_rate:
   sound = sound.set_frame_rate(desired_sample_rate) # convert to 16000 khz sample rate
sound = effects.normalize(sound) # normalize audio file
dBFS = sound.dBFS # get decibels relative to full scale
sound_chunks = split_on_silence(sound,
                                min_silence_len = 200, # measured in ms
                                silence_thresh = dBFS -30 # if DBFS goes 30 below the file's dBFS it will be considered "silence"
)


# this "audio_segment_0.wav" file came from the above code.
audio_file_path = Path("audio_segment_0.wav")

raw_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_file_path).set_frame_rate(16000)

# append 200 ms of silence to beginning and end of file
raw_audio = effects.normalize(raw_audio)
silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration = 200, frame_rate = 16000)
raw_audio_w_silence = silence + raw_audio + silence

# export it
raw_audio_w_silence.export("pydub_audio.wav", format = 'wav') # the output from this sounds completely OK.

# read audio, manipulate and write with soundfile
new_audio = AudioSegment.from_file("pydub_audio.wav").set_frame_rate(16000)
new_audio_signal = np.array(new_audio.get_array_of_samples(), dtype = np.float32) / 32768.0 # scale to between [-1.0, 1.0]

# the output from down here using the scaled numpy array sounds about half the speed as the first.
sf.write("soundfile_export.wav", data = new_audio_signal, samplerate = new_audio.frame_rate, format = 'wav')
```

Comment: What is the original sample rate and type of audio_segment_0.wav?

Comment: It came from pydub.split_on_silence. I'll add that to the code in my original post. The original file was an hour long audio .mp3 that came from Youtube.

Comment: @amiasato I updated the post with info. The original mp3 was 44100 khz, I converted it to 16000 khz, then split it on silence.